Access a Kubernetes service from a local machine without manually port forwarding
When running Kubernetes locally using Kind, to access a service, I need to open a terminal and forward the port every time with the following command:
kubectl port-forward <podname> 80:80

After running this, I can access the service using "http://localhost/".
What is the proper way to configure it so that I don't have to manually run the port-forward command every time, allowing me to access the service directly using "http://localhost/"?
The service is very basic, as shown below for reference:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80


The proper way is to use ClusterIP for your service and expose it using an ingress. You'll have to read up on how to do that with Kind. BR

The Kind documentation has a page on Ingress and it does involve cluster-level configuration to publish a port out of the Kubernetes environment to the host.
